# Modify a class with typed traits in Scala

Tags: scala, type-traits, parser-combinators

I've been playing around with Scala recently, and when working with parser combinators, I kind of had some problems extending them. Basically, what I'm trying to do is something like this.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

abstract class Statement

case object Foo extends Statement
case object Bar extends Statement
case object Baz extends Statement

class Program(statements: List[Statement])

class FooBarLanguageParser extends RegexParsers {
  def program: Parser[Program] = rep(statement) ^^ (v => new Program(List() ++ v))
  def statement: Parser[Statement] = foo|bar
  def foo: Parser[Statement] = "foo" ^^ (_ => Foo)
  def bar: Parser[Statement] = "bar" ^^ (_ => Bar)
}

trait BazStatement { this: FooBarLanguageParser =>
  override def statement: Parser[Statement] = baz|this.statement  // inifinite recursion
  def baz: Parser[Statement] = "baz" ^^ (_ => Baz)
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val normalFooBar = new FooBarLanguageParser()
    val fooBarProgram = normalFooBar.parseAll(normalFooBar.program, "foo bar")
    val extendedFooBar = new FooBarLanguageParser() with BazStatement
    val extendedFooBarProgram = extendedFooBar.parseAll(extendedFooBar.program,
       "foo bar baz")
    println(fooBarProgram.successful)
    println(extendedFooBarProgram.successful)
  }
}
```

Here, I would like to call `FooBarLanguageParser`'s `statement` method in `BazStatement`, but with the above code I'm recursively calling `BazStatement`'s method, so no way it would work properly.

I already took a look at the answers around, and I know that I could extend the class and use abstract override, or somethink like this, but I don't think it would really make any sense here, as `BazStatement` is really an additional feature I want to mixin with my basic parser. I definitely don't want to have some random things like

```
object StrangeInheritance extends BazStatement
```

authorized in the code.

Would there be any idiomatic way to do this properly in Scala or do I need to think again about the general design of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use super to call supertype's method, also use traits to define top-level abstractions. This one runs ok:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

abstract class Statement

case object Foo extends Statement
case object Bar extends Statement
case object Baz extends Statement

class Program(statements: List[Statement])

trait FooBarLanguageParser extends RegexParsers {
  def program: Parser[Program] = rep(statement) ^^ (v => new Program(List() ++ v))
  def statement: Parser[Statement] = foo|bar
  def foo: Parser[Statement] = "foo" ^^ (_ => Foo)
  def bar: Parser[Statement] = "bar" ^^ (_ => Bar)
}

trait BazStatement extends FooBarLanguageParser {
  override def statement: Parser[Statement] = baz| super.statement  // inifinite recursion
  def baz: Parser[Statement] = "baz" ^^ (_ => Baz)
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val normalFooBar = new FooBarLanguageParser() {}
    val fooBarProgram = normalFooBar.parseAll(normalFooBar.program, "foo bar")
    val extendedFooBar = new FooBarLanguageParser() with BazStatement
    val extendedFooBarProgram = extendedFooBar.parseAll(extendedFooBar.program,
       "foo bar baz")
    println(fooBarProgram.successful)
    println(extendedFooBarProgram.successful)
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. The thing about this code is that `object FooBar extends BazStatement` would work perfectly and I would be able to use all the methods in `FooBarLanguageParser`, which I find kind of akward as I want `BazStatement` to be a single extra functionality to my `FooBarLanguageParser`.

Comment: Actually mixins (traits) are very idiomatic scala way that provides ad-hoc modularity. I think this is default option if you want to provide a way to combine a set of discreet behaviours into one runtime object. You may be right that indeed mixins might not work here as it's hard to design your top-level Parser in an extensible way. Maybe having a set of general rules in some utility traits and then constructing your 'concrete' bottom parser with the help of this "general rules" traits would be a better option then trying to use inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I'll go as you said with a top level traits defining general rules and some concrete implementations.